# Want to switch to Error list after Build if there were errors

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I develop in C# using VS 2008.

Is there a way to configure VS 2008 so if there were Build Errors it will automatically switch to "Error List" window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VS2008, Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General > check the **Always show Error List if build finishes with errors**.

Comment: Works in VS2012 as well

Answer (score 0):

Whether the error list is pinned or set to "auto-hide," when the build fails it will be visible with the list of errors. At that point if you hit an arrow key to traverse the list, it becomes focused and you can navigate the window.

I don't know of any options or preferences which alter this behavior.